# index vs a-specific-url

Tags: seo, url

As we all know, the URL has some importance in SEO.

Should I try to rewrite (or redirect) the index page to a specific-name?

For example:

index.php to white-cats-are-cute.php

(This is regardless of the domain name or the directory name, it is very specific to the index file)

---

Edited:

1. The case is a bit specific. The domain itself has no keyword, but an abstract name. Let us imagine something like example.com which says nothing about the type of product or services.
2. It is a One Page website, so it has no other pages that could hint about the product, like example.com/hamburger.html, so the only page it has is index.html.

So, yes it is to have a keyword on the URL, (of course besides a good title and description)

Comment: For what purpose?  To try to get keywords into the URL?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question a bit.

Comment: (I am studying deeply the related question to see if it really fits my case)